# How to use minimum sdk to support older android software , when APK used in app requires high minimum sdk?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, apk, compatibility

I am new in mobile application developing. I am using the android studio to build the application. 
The minimumsdk=14 and the targetsdk=28 for my project.
I developed the application's first version and I checked it on my mobile phone(Samsung Galaxy S9, Android Version:8.0) and it works perfectly.
To share the app with the testers devices I uploaded the .apk file online and I gave the link to download it on the devices and then install it. 
All the devices have access to a third party (unknown sources) to install apps.
Although, after installing the application, they run the app on their devices and App stop working. 
Do you think that the minimum SDK is the problem? Maybe is too high to support many devices?
Can I use an apk only when it is supported? And have a minimum SDK different than the minimum sdk for a specific apk?
I want to use apk that are supported from newer versions SDK but continue to be compatible with older versions of SDKs.
Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - How do you support older API's without having 2 compiled .apk files when you use methods from newer API's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571113/android-how-do-you-support-older-apis-without-having-2-compiled-apk-files-wh)

Comment: You need to make sure you are making android build as it is supposed to be made..

Comment: I use build grandle to build..I don't understand your answer can you please explain more?

Comment: Check for current API level, wrap newer API calls in `if (...)` blocks and fall back to alternatives that work on older apis in the else branch.